# Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ERRMODE_EXPECTION'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to build a register system and to store username and password in DB

I wrote code with PHP but I got an error with PDO and I can't find a solution
Error:

> Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ERRMODE_EXPECTION' in /storage/ssd4/295/11285295/public_html/config.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd4/295/11285295/public_html/index.php(2): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd4/295/11285295/public_html/config.php on line 8

My code :

```
<?php
$db_user = "id11285295_useraccounts";
$db_password = "(my password here)";
$db_name = "id11285295_useraccounts";


$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;db_name=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8',  $db_user, $db_password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXPECTION);
```

Also, I have another register page that requires this to work

Comment: *"to store username and password into phpmyadmin with php"*  phpmyadmin is not a RDMS by the way...

Comment: try using an underscore, viz: `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: *"try using an underscore, viz: utf8_unicode_ci"* Will not help @RamRaider  it should be `charset=utf8` instead ... `utf8_unicode_ci` is a collation not a charset..

Comment: yep: my bad, you are totally correct

Comment: question changed

Comment: *"Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ERRMODE_EXPECTION' "* Not `PDO::ERRMODE_EXPECTION` but `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`  ...

Comment: THANKSSS SO MUCH IT WORKED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error line says the problem is with the specified character set. `utf8-unicode-ci` is a collation under character set `utf8`, not a character set.

See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html) about the character sets.

Comment: is this the long way around telling the topicstarter that `charset=utf8` instead should be used ??

Comment: More like a friendly introduction to charsets and collations ;). The recommended charset would be `utf8mb4`.

Comment: Use the `utf8mb4` as `utf-8` is not a valid charset either (`utf8` would be, but it is a subset of `utf8mb4`). See the documentation link.

Comment: *"More like a friendly introduction to charsets and collations ;)."* Fair enough :-) *"The recommended charset would be utf8mb4"* depending on the MySQL version..

Comment: `utf8mb4` was included in MySQL 5.5.3 (almost 10 years ago). If one is still running MySQL pre 5.5.3, would recommend to upgrade..

Comment: well i agree to that but did you consider that the topicstarter might be running on a shared webhosting environment with a older version?  Anyhow we are moving way to much offtopic by making to much assumptions ;-) and also the topicstarter found his answer..